# React: conditional rendering and discrimination union

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Goal**

Simplify the following situation

```
// Simplify
loading ? <Loading/> : (
  <Fragment>
    ....
  </Fragment>
) 

// Into something like
<LoadingContent loading={loading}>
 {() => (
   <Fragment>
     ...
   </Fragment>
 )}
</LoadingContent>
```

**Problem**

if the loading condition is an attribute of an object, used for [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions), access properties based on this attribute being true will not be infered, and it'll not compile.

**Current solution**

Use short circuit the evaluation with logical &&, but it duplicate the condition and the aim is to make it simpler.

```
<LoadingContent loading={loading}>
 {() => loading && (
   <Fragment>
     ...
   </Fragment>
 )}
</LoadingContent>
```

**From proposal:**

Problem, generic type must be specified and can't be inferred due to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597

```
interface LoadingDiscriminatedContentProps<
  A extends string,
  S,
  SS extends S,
  O extends { [P in A]: S }
> {
  object: O;
  attribute: A;
  discriminant: SS;
  children: (loaded: Extract<O, O & { [P in A]: SS }>) => React.ReactElement;
}

export function LoadingDiscriminatedContent<
  A extends string,
  S,
  SS extends S,
  O extends { [P in A]: S }
>({
  object,
  attribute,
  discriminant,
  children
}: LoadingDiscriminatedContentProps<A, S, SS, O>): React.ReactElement {
  if (object[attribute] === (discriminant as S)) {
    return children(object as Extract<O, O & { [P in A]: SS }>);
  }
  return <Loading />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this. The key was that LoadingContent calls the children callback with type `T & {loaded: true}`.

LoadingContent.tsx:

```js
interface Props<L extends string, T extends { [P in L]: boolean }> {
    value: T;
    loadedProp: L;
    children: (loaded: T & { [P in L]: true }) => React.ReactElement;
}

const LoadingContent = <L extends string, T extends { [P in L]: boolean }>({value, loadedProp, children}: Props<L, T>): React.ReactElement => {
    if (value[loadedProp]) {
        return children(value as any);
    }
    return <>Loading...</>;
}
```

Usage:

```js
interface LoadedData {
    loaded: true;
    data: string;
}

interface LoadingData {
    loaded: false;
}

type Data = LoadedData | LoadingData;

const obj: Data = {loaded: true, data: ''};

const el = (
    <LoadingContent value={obj} loadedProp="loaded">
        {(obj) => (
            <>
                {obj.data /* here we can use obj.data*/}
            </>
        )}
    </LoadingContent>
);
```

If your "loaded" property is always the same, you can omit the generic L type

Comment: Nice ! Will definitly play with that to see if I can found something where loadedProp can be any discriminant (not only a booleanne)

Comment: I found a generic solution which is ugly because of: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597 (see from proposal)